# Creating a dictionary from a list and fixed variable in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary from a list and a fixed variable. I know that `zip()` can create a dictionary from two lists but how can I adapt it to intake a fixed variable?

What works:

```
countries = ["Italy", "Germany", "Spain", "USA", "Switzerland"]
dishes = ["pizza", "sauerkraut", "paella", "Hamburger"]
country_specialities = zip(countries, dishes)
```

What I need:

```
dishes = ["pizza", "sauerkraut", "paella", "Hamburger"]
country = "uk"
```

To output:

```
menu = {"pizza": "uk", "sauerkraut": "uk", "paella": "uk", "Hamburger": "uk"}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Making a list with `'uk'` in it four times seems pretty trivial, for example, then you can pass it to `zip` as before.

Comment: I used those values as an example, the real list has almost 200,000 values

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
{dish: country for dish in dishes}
```

Comment: A dictionary comprehension is actually overkill, not when you can simply use `dict.fromkeys(dishes, country)` here (which would be faster).

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`dict.fromkeys()` class method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) here:

```
dict.fromkeys(dishes, country)
```

Note that you should *not* use this where the default is a mutable value (unless you meant to share that mutable value among all the keys).

From the documentation:

> Create a new dictionary with keys from *seq* and values set to *value*.
>
> `fromkeys()` is a class method that returns a new dictionary. *value* defaults to `None`.

This is going to be faster than using a dictionary comprehension; the looping over `dishes` is done entirely in C code, while a dict comprehension would execute the loop in Python bytecode instead.

If your list is going to contain 200.000 values, then that makes a huge difference:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> import random
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase
>>> values = [''.join([random.choice(ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(random.randint(20, 40))]) for _ in range(200000)]
>>> def dictcomp(values):
...     return {v: 'default' for v in values}
... 
>>> def dictfromkeys(values):
...     return dict.fromkeys(values, 'default')
... 
>>> timeit('f(values)', 'from __main__ import values, dictcomp as f', number=100)
4.984026908874512
>>> timeit('f(values)', 'from __main__ import values, dictfromkeys as f', number=100)
4.159089803695679
```

That's almost a second of difference between the two options when repeating the operation 100 times.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
dishes = ["pizza", "sauerkraut", "paella", "Hamburger"]
country = "uk"
menu = dict((dish, country) for dish in dishes)
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on with what you were doing with `zip`

```
In [54]: dict(zip(dishes, [country] * len(dishes)) )
Out[54]: {'Hamburger': 'uk', 'paella': 'uk', 'pizza': 'uk', 'sauerkraut': 'uk'}
```